# How can I stop my logo from floating to right while I increase the screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```
.header-logo{
    max-width: 172px;
    
    /* width: 100%;  */
   
    max-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 30px;
     
    margin-top: 5px;     
}
```

My coding for logo image.

Comment: This css alone doesn’t make a logo float to the right, can you include your full html/css that reproduces the problem?

Comment: <div className="header-desktop-main-div">
    {banner ?<div className="banner">  Special deal: Simply sign in and test out your VPN for last 30 days <CloseIcon onClick={handleClose} className={classes.closeIcon}/> </div>: null }
    <Container maxWidth="lg">
        <div className="header-main-div">
          <Grid container spacing={1}>
            <Grid  item xs={3}>
           <Link to="/">   <img className="header-logo" src={new_logo} alt="logo"/> </Link>
            </Grid>

Comment: header main div css:
.header-main-div{
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color:"#f6f6f9";
    
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the information you added in the comments.  That way, those reading your question won't have to read all the comments, and the code can be better formatted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this CSS-code to that Logo:

```
display:block;
```